# How to compare float or double?

Tags: c++

Is there built-in library can compare float or double

I do not think compare like `a == b` or `a !=b` makes any sense. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the technique to compare floats or doubles is to use [`fabs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/)

```
bool isEqual(const float a,const float b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
}
```

You can use epsilon for the floats or doubles from [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use:

```
fabs(a-b) < eps  // eps is the precision you want to achieve
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this function :

```
template <typename T>
bool approx(const T& x, const T& y, const T& eps = 1.0e-10)
{
  if(x == y)
    return true;
  if(x == 0.0)
    return (y < 0.0 ? -y : y) < eps;
  if(y == 0.0)
    return (x < 0.0 ? -x : x) < eps;
  return (x < y ? y - x : x - y) < eps * ((x < 0.0 ? -x : x) + (y < 0.0 ? -y : y)) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: This function looks much more complicated than it needs to be.